# Pandas fails with correct data type while reading a SAS file

Tags: python, pandas, types, sas

I have a [SAS dataset](http://www.principlesofeconometrics.com/sas/cars.sas7bdat) and when I run it I get the following output on SAS:

[image]

I also have the following Python code which gets the .sas7bdat file and displays the output, i.e. here the first five observations.

```
import pandas as pd
file_name = "cars.sas7bdat"
my_df = pd.read_sas(file_name)
my_df = my_df.head()
print(my_df)
```

[image]

As you can see, it doesn't work correct when it comes to integer data types. CYL and WGT variables are integers but are not displaying correctly if I use pandas' [read_sas function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_sas.html).

Any idea what heck is going on with this?

Comment: Without knowing more about your data, I guess they are the raw values that SAS exports and it just applies an `int` filter when it displays them to you. Is there a way to explore the cars.sas7bdat file in a text editor?

Answer (score 2):

SAS represents all numbers as 64bit (8 byte) floating point numbers. But you can save disk space by telling it to store less than 8 bytes.  The dataset you posted did this for CYL and WGT.

[image]

When SAS reads the dataset back from disk to use it sets the missing least significant bytes to binary zeros. Apparently `read_sas` didn't understand this and instead of setting the missing bytes to binary zeros it did something else.  Hence the seemingly random data.

The first value of CYL is `8` which in IEEE floating point would be the hexcode

```
40 20 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

The value you displayed of `8.00046` would be this value instead.

```
40 20 00 06 07 80 FD C1
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved the issue. Well, that seems definitely pandas' bug. I used directly the .sas7bdat library by typing this(installing):

```
pip install sas7bdat
```

Then I run the following code:

```
import sas7bdat
from sas7bdat import *

file_name = file_path + "cars.sas7bdat"
foo = SAS7BDAT(file_name)
my_df = foo.to_data_frame()
my_df = my_df.head()
print(my_df)
```

After running the above code, I get the following output in Python:

[image]

So, I get the output with correct data types displayed.

Hope pandas developers find out a solutions for the mentioned bug above.

Comment: I really don't think it's a bug but you didn't reply to my initial comment. SAS is proprietary so I can't test locally.

Comment: Sorry @roganjosh . I don't know any text editor which can run SAS data but what I did is to download/install sas university edition (free for non-commercial use). There, you just need to run proc print data="/folders/myfolders/cars.sas7bdat"; run; and get the same output above. The other option would be to use this 
 http://dumbmatter.com/sas7bdat/ for displaying sas data in a tabular format.

Comment: There's also the SAS Viewer which is free and allows you view SAS data sets and export them as CSV files. This data set is the same as the cars data set available in the tidyverse package, and possibly others. https://support.sas.com/downloads/package.htm?pid=667

Comment: Thanks @Reeza. By the way, the version of pandas I used was/is 0.22.0