# How can I preserve the data type of a column when using pandas.read_sas()?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

All column types are converted to **floats** (column type is not preserved) when read from [this SAS file](http://www.principlesofeconometrics.com/sas/airline.sas7bdat) into a pandas dataframe.

Following is the Python code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

data_dir = os.getcwd()
sas_file = os.path.join(data_dir, 'airline.sas7bdat')

iter_sas = pd.read_sas(sas_file, iterator=True, chunksize=1000)

for chunk in iter_sas:
    print(chunk.head())
```

Outputting the following:

```
          YEAR      Y      W       R      L      K
0  1948.000888  1.214  0.243  0.1454  1.415  0.612
1  1949.000888  1.354  0.260  0.2181  1.384  0.559
2  1950.000011  1.569  0.278  0.3157  1.388  0.573
3  1951.000011  1.948  0.297  0.3940  1.550  0.564
4  1952.000000  2.265  0.310  0.3559  1.802  0.574
```

How can I preserve the column's data type when using `pandas.read_sas()`?

Comment: Related / possible duplicate: [Pandas fails with correct data type while reading a SAS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49059421/pandas-fails-with-correct-data-type-while-reading-a-sas-file)

Comment: I don't understand. Float is the only numeric data type that SAS dataset have.

Comment: Actually your dataset has numbers stored with fewer than the full 8 bytes.  Apparently `pandas.read_sas` has not yet fixed the bug identified in the question JPP linked.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49059421/pandas-fails-with-correct-data-type-while-reading-a-sas-file?noredirect=1&lq=1), you have to first import the following

```
from sas7bdat import SAS7BDAT
```

and then cast your file as

```
SAS7BDAT("airline.sas7bdat")
```

Then you can convert it to a data frame.

```
   YEAR      Y      W       R      L      K
0  1948.0  1.214  0.243  0.1454  1.415  0.612
1  1949.0  1.354  0.260  0.2181  1.384  0.559
2  1950.0  1.569  0.278  0.3157  1.388  0.573
3  1951.0  1.948  0.297  0.3940  1.550  0.564
4  1952.0  2.265  0.310  0.3559  1.802  0.574
```

Comment: It looks like this still has floats for year. Also, how would SAS7BDAT be used while chunking in pandas.read_sas()?

Comment: if your dataframe is called DF, you can call: DF["YEAR"] = DF["YEAR"].astype('int64'). Likewise, you can call SAS7BDAT on each chunk before you actually change the float to an int, as such:   chunk = SAS7BDAT(chunk), then chunk["YEAR"] = chunk["YEAR].astype('int64'

Comment: So you're saying I have to manually apply the type to the column. Is there no way to preserve it from the sas7bdat file?

Comment: Not per pandas doc.

Comment: SAS stores all numbers as floating point.  You can apply different formats to have them displayed in different ways.  You could possibly write some logic to assume that a variable only contains integers when the creator of the dataset had applied a display format with no decimal places.  But pandas.read_sas does not have any capability to make that guess for you.  I don't think that it even returns the SAS metadata about the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `read_sas` still has the same bug as in the other question. The first variable, `YEAR`, is stored using only 4 bytes and `read_sas` is making up numbers to fill out the missing 4 bytes instead of filling them with zero bytes.

[image]

Either find another package that actually understands SAS dataset structure or round or convert the values after reading them in.

Comment: Can you suggest another package that can chunk?

Comment: From other answer it looks like `sas7bdat` reads the file correctly.  Remember that SAS stores all numbers as floating points.

Comment: That doesn't chunk AFAIK, do you know a way to chunk (so as not hold the entire dataset in memory)?

Comment: For this specific dataset since we can reasonably assume from the name of the problem column that it should contain four digit integers I would just truncate the values to integers after reading from the SAS dataset.

Comment: This was an example dataset, the actual dataset has hundreds of columns of various types.

Comment: You can use other tools that properly read SAS datasets. Such as the readstat package that is used by the R package haven.  Or Stat Transfer.  Or see if you can have the SAS datasets created using length=8 for all numeric variables.